# I've been offered a position as a Senior UX Designer in a small town

Tags: jobs

I've been offered a position as a Senior UX Designer in a small town. Although I have never been titled as a Senior Designer, I have the experience and resume of one (if not higher). I was never fortunate to go higher than that at any agency I have worked.  The Senior employees I have worked with were not very different than my role and experience. It's confusing. I know I have what it takes, but unsure of this confidence.

This role will have a team built around that position.

My question is: What does it *take* to be in this role? What should be expected of you? Is it something you learn over time? Should I pass on the position?

Comment: Im curious too. Because I too am wondering what it entails to become a Senior UX Designer. I think the years has a lot to do with it. People tell me I'm pretty good at what I do, but I'm also wondering if I need to wait an x amount of years before I can be promoted.

Comment: If you want the job, like the company/pay/location, then why pass? You need to leave your comfort zone to grow. Will you be supervising? Managing a budget? Scheduling/assigning tasks? Have you done any of that before? If you've had bad bosses, don't be them; emulate the good ones. Read up on being an effective leader & project manager. Don't worry about proclaiming your competence & experience, often a mark of people who don't have either. Instead, demonstrate it & help your coworkers grow while helping the team succeed. Everything is something you learn over time. Enjoy it!

Comment: I agree with @mc01 - that's what I plan on doing, no reason why you can't either!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question doesn't belong on UX.SE because there's no correct answer here. Try Quora - career advice there is stellar.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it take to be in this role?

It takes a business card that has "senior" in your job title.

That's really all. It's nothing specific other than, in theory, you have more experience than the other folks on the team (and hopefully a correlated higher salary).

Comment: https://twitter.com/dburka/status/555496843920961536

Answer (score 0):

If they have offered you the job, then they have looked at your experience, compared it with the job role, and decided you're a good fit.

Remember: everyone who is currently a Senior UX Designer was once a middle-weight UX Designer.